# only file name index.php is not working on apache2

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using apache2 on ubuntu. My localhost is working fine and also php is working.

But only file name index.php is not working. If the file name is test.php or anything othe than index.php, it works.

Dont know it is apache prob or php, can anyone please help?

Thankx,
Kamil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid the htaccess file and edit http.conf.  It should be the same listing DirectoryIndex there too.  Add index.php and see if you get php to render.

Out of curiosity what do you see when you view index.html?  It works! ?

Comment: thanks, DirectoryIndex was not on httpd.conf file. noe working

Comment: There is going to be one somewhere.  If its apache2 then you might have a sites folder somewhere with a default .conf file. Put something like this in there  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean it's not recognized? You can try to add it to your `.htaccess` file in the root of your webserver:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: no, it is recognizing. But is not executing. http://localhost.test.php is showing the output, but http://localhost/index.php is showing a blank page. But both have the same codes.